# Javassist: Side effects of ClassPool.makeClass()?

Tags: java, classloader, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

I'm investigating a strange **exception** when running a **java 8** application instrumented by an **agent** which uses **Javassist**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.invoke.CallSite
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
        ... 7 more
```

During further investigation, it seems that Javassist's [`ClassPool.makeClass()`](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/ClassPool.html#makeClass-java.io.InputStream-) causes this. There must be some (Classloading?) **side effects when calling this method**.
The minimalistic version of my `ClassFileTransformer` which already reproduces the bug is:

```
  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
      Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
      byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException
  {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    try
    {
      CtClass makeClass = pool.makeClass(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(
          classfileBuffer));
    }
    catch (IOException | RuntimeException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return classfileBuffer;
  }
```

As you can see, I'm always returning the untouched `byte[]` representation of the class, I'm not modifying any classes.
 **When removing the line with `pool.makeClass()`, the application behaves normally.**

**Question:**
Can you give me an hint what's wrong here and what side-effects of `makeClass()` are causing this?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to transform a class which `Javassist` itself needs?

Comment: @Holger As stated in the question - I am not transforming anything. I'm returning the original, untouched classfileBuffer. I just invoke ClassPool.makeClass() which basically parses the classfileBuffer and prepares internal data structures.

Comment: Maybe we should define the word “transform” first. You are transforming a class, when your method `transform` gets called, thus, in the case of load-time transformation, the class is *not* ready to use until your method returns. When your `transform` method gets called with a class that `Javassist` itself needs and you are trying to use `Javassist`, you have a circular dependency. By the way, if you are not changing the class, I recommend returning `null` to tell the JVM that you didn’t change anything. Otherwise, the JVM doesn’t know whether you have written to the array.

Comment: @Holger Thank you, you are right on both points (even though returning an unchanged buffer has no impact here). Excluding java core classes from pool.makeClass() solved my issue. I wish I could accept your comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform load-time transformation, your `transform` method gets called for all classes that are attempted to get loaded, once you transformer has been installed. This includes the classes required by Javassist itself, if they haven’t been loaded yet. So if you don’t exclude these classes, you are creating a circular dependency. It seems that the JVM reacts with a `NoClassDefFoundError` when you try to use a class for which a transformer is still running (within the same thread).

As a side note, if you are not changing the class, I recommend returning `null` to tell the JVM that you didn’t change anything. Otherwise, the JVM doesn’t know whether you have written to the array and has to re-parse the data (or compare them to the original bytes to find out that they are not changed). This is only a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I see `CallSite`, it looks like the lambda magic done by the Java 8 compiler to support bootstrapping the lambda callsite to `invokedynamic`. See the Javadoc for [LambdaMetaFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) for more details.

Is Javasisst fully compatible with Java 8?